Attempting to flatten a list of dictionaries to a Dataframe but can't get to the lowest level information with json-normalise

Below is the output of an API call - it is a dictionary which contains a list of dictionaries I'm interested in under 'response'
I filter fixture_ids for 'response' because the rest is not useful information
it returns a list of dictionaries I'm interested in. I want to get the lowest level stats for each team in the structure of table below but I can't get there no matter what I try with json_normalize

url = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/fixtures/statistics"

querystring = {"fixture":"1220142"}

headers = {
    "x-rapidapi-key": "MY_KEY",
    "x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

fixture_ids = response.json()

{'get': 'fixtures/statistics',
 'parameters': {'fixture': '1220142'},
 'errors': [],
 'results': 2,
 'paging': {'current': 1, 'total': 1},
 'response': [{'team': {'id': 250,
    'name': 'Kilmarnock',
    'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/250.png'},
   'statistics': [{'type': 'Shots on Goal', 'value': 3},
    {'type': 'Shots off Goal', 'value': 7},
    {'type': 'Total Shots', 'value': 15},
    {'type': 'Blocked Shots', 'value': 5},
    {'type': 'Shots insidebox', 'value': 14},
    {'type': 'Shots outsidebox', 'value': 1},
    {'type': 'Fouls', 'value': 8},
    {'type': 'Corner Kicks', 'value': 7},
    {'type': 'Offsides', 'value': None},
    {'type': 'Ball Possession', 'value': '48%'},
    {'type': 'Yellow Cards', 'value': 1},
    {'type': 'Red Cards', 'value': None},
    {'type': 'Goalkeeper Saves', 'value': 5},
    {'type': 'Total passes', 'value': 349},
    {'type': 'Passes accurate', 'value': 248},
    {'type': 'Passes %', 'value': '71%'},
    {'type': 'expected_goals', 'value': None},
    {'type': 'goals_prevented', 'value': None}]},
  {'team': {'id': 1386,
    'name': 'Dundee Utd',
    'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/1386.png'},
   'statistics': [{'type': 'Shots on Goal', 'value': 8},
    {'type': 'Shots off Goal', 'value': 4},
    {'type': 'Total Shots', 'value': 19},
    {'type': 'Blocked Shots', 'value': 7},
    {'type': 'Shots insidebox', 'value': 13},
    {'type': 'Shots outsidebox', 'value': 6},
    {'type': 'Fouls', 'value': 12},
    {'type': 'Corner Kicks', 'value': 3},
    {'type': 'Offsides', 'value': None},
    {'type': 'Ball Possession', 'value': '52%'},
    {'type': 'Yellow Cards', 'value': 2},
    {'type': 'Red Cards', 'value': None},
    {'type': 'Goalkeeper Saves', 'value': 0},
    {'type': 'Total passes', 'value': 379},
    {'type': 'Passes accurate', 'value': 258},
    {'type': 'Passes %', 'value': '68%'},
    {'type': 'expected_goals', 'value': None},
    {'type': 'goals_prevented', 'value': None}]}]}

What I tried with fixture_ids is below:
fixture_ids = fixture_ids['response']
new = pd.json_normalize(fixture_ids,record_path='statistics',meta=[['team','id']])

The below works in that it gives me the different types like shots on goal but they are in a single column with their value to the right per below. I want to have the 'type' a column header e.g. 'type.shots on goal' with the value underneath it.



type
value
team.id




shots on Goal
3
250


Shots off Goal
7
250


.....
....
...


shots on Goal
8
1386


Shots off Goal
4
1386


.....
....
...



The output I want is below. Thank you.



Team ID
Shots on Goal
Shots off Goal




250
3
7


1386
8
4




try https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

As per the suggested duplicate, use df.pivot afterwards. E.g., new.pivot(index='team.id', columns='type', values='value').loc[:, new['type']]. The additional df.loc gets you the columns in the suggested order.
